# Table sorting by clicking on column headers

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue with sorting data in a table by clicking on column name. I tried many solutions for this. But the problem is that, it seem to work fine when I add rows to the table using javascript insertRow() method. After inserting the new rows, when I am clicking on any column, the old data is only getting sorted and new row I inserted through javascript is getting disappeared. And here is the code:
You can find the gs_sortable.js file in this link http://www.allmyscripts.com/Table_Sort/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var TSort_Data = new Array ('my_table', 's', 'd', 'c', 'i');              
    </script>
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body><h3 align="center" >
    </h3><table class="table-autosort" width="100%"> <table id="my_table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="25%">Product</th>
                    <th width="25%">Date</th>
                    <th  width="25%">Price per unit</th>
                    <th width="25%">Units sold</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td width="25%" >Item A</td>
                <td width="25%">14/5/2012</td>
                <td width="25%">$28</td>
                <td width="25%"> 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="25%"> Item B</td>
                <td width="25%">14/5/2012</td>
                <td width="25%">$35</td>
                <td width="25%">1</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="25%">Item A</td>
                <td width="25%">13/5/2012</td>
                <td width="25%">$25.15</td>
                <td width="25%">20</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="25%">Item C</td>
                <td width="25%">15/5/2012</td>
                <td width="25%">$20</td>
                <td width="25%">100</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Insert new row</button>
    </table>

</body>
```

I want the new row to be in the sorted list when I click on column headings.

Thank you

Comment: You can use [Datatables jquery plugin](http://datatables.net/) for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle with a solution http://jsfiddle.net/GbGx5/4/

The import thing is to re-register the table data with tsort after you've called insertRow, otherwise the data cached inside tsort will only contain the old table data.

To do this call the following methods (as recommended in the documentation under *Using script with dynamically loaded tables* http://www.allmyscripts.com/Table_Sort/#example)

```
// Make sure we refresh the TSort_Data Array!
TSort_Data = new Array ('my_table', 's', 'd', 'c', 'i');
tsRegister();
tsSetTable('my_table');
tsInit();
```

The full JavaScript of the example is as follows...

```
var TSort_Data = new Array ('my_table', 's', 'd', 'c', 'i');              

function insertNewRow() {
    var table=document.getElementById("my_table"),
        newRowIndex = table.getElementsByTagName('tr').length,
        row=table.insertRow(newRowIndex),
        cell1=row.insertCell(0),
        cell2=row.insertCell(1),
        cell3=row.insertCell(2),        
        cell4=row.insertCell(3);

    cell1.innerHTML = "New Item";
    cell2.innerHTML = "15/10/2013";
    cell3.innerHTML = "$5";
    cell4.innerHTML = 51;    

    // Make sure we refresh the TSort_Data Array!
    TSort_Data = new Array ('my_table', 's', 'd', 'c', 'i');
    tsRegister();
    tsSetTable('my_table');
    tsInit();    
}
```